# Update button not functioning

Tags: asp.net

My update button is not functioning. Whenever I want to update any record, it will not works.

Radio button must be checked in order to update any records in a gridview. After the button is checked, the user will click an update button (located above the gridview). then a page will be displayed. the page will display all the information (in a form view) of the user. he/ she will just change any information they want. after that the user should click update button located below. It is like submitting the form again. But the form is not updated. What should i change?

Below is the code for update button:

```
protected void update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (Page.IsValid)
{
string datestart_s = (string)(Session["datestart"]);
datestart_s = Convert.ToDateTime(datestart_s).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
string leavetype_c = (string)(Session["leavetype"]);

string X = TextBox3.Text;

string substring1 = X;
string substring2 = "";

foreach (string value in X.Split('-'))
if (X.Length > 40)
{
substring1 = X.Substring(0, 40);
if (X.Length == 80)
{
substring2 = X.Substring(39, 40);
}
else
{
int Xlength = X.Length - 40;
substring2 = X.Substring(40, Xlength);
}
}

OdbcConnection connection = null;
OdbcCommand com = null;

string queryString = "UPDATE QMBSTEST.SCEMLV SET LVTYPE='" + leave.SelectedItem.Value + "', LVDTST='" + start.Text + "', LVDTED='" + end.Text + "', LVDAYS='" + TextBox2.Text + "', LVAMPM='" + time.SelectedItem.Value + "', LVTEXT1='" + substring1 + "', LVTEXT2='" + substring2 + "', LVFLAG='" + apply.SelectedItem.Value + "' WHERE LVEMID='" + TB_EMPID.Text.Trim().ToUpper() + "' AND LVDTST='" + datestart_s.Trim() + "' AND LVTYPE='" + leavetype_c.Trim() + "'";

connection = new OdbcConnection(@"Dsn=as400;Uid=FATIN;Pwd=FATIN;");

com = new OdbcCommand(queryString, connection);

connection.Open();

com.ExecuteNonQuery();

connection.Close();

lblMessage.Text = "Form updated!";
lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.GreenYellow;

}
}
```

Comment: You need to give us more information. You said the form is not updated, this could mean anything. Does the record in the DB change? Do you get an error message? You have to be more detailed about the error and you might want to add the HTML for this page as well.

Comment: @matt_lethargic not updated meaning that the record was not changed. I didnt get any error. when i click the update button, it will says the form is updated but when i double check it, it is actually not

Comment: So you mean the row in the database doesn't get updated. Have you stepped into your code and found out what the value of queryString is to make sure the SQL you're building is correct? You would be better off using Parameters to pass in the data for the SQL have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.data.odbc.odbcparameter(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Are you validating that event with any customvalidator?
If yes then replace :

```
if (Page.IsValid)
```

> With

```
IF(!IsValild)
  return:
```

and then ur code.....
Because you not doing anything when any of your validation through validation control got failed.

Comment: i replaced but nothing happened

Comment: Try debug your code and check whether it is coding into the update query section or not? You will get your answer..